# Errors with imports with specific directory tree when running test

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, import, directory

I have created some test for a project I am in and there appears to be some issues when importing modules from the modules to test. I have simplified my project as in the following working tree:

```
├── project_name
    ├── data
        ├── modules
        |     ├── __init__.py
        |     ├── module_A.py
        |     ├── module_B.py
        ├── test
              ├── __init__.py
              ├── test_module_A.py
```

Inside `modules/__init__.py`

```
from . import module_A
from . import module_B
```

Inside `module_A.py`

```
from module_B import function_b

def function_a():
    pass
```

Inside `module_B.py`

```
def function_b():
    pass
```

Inside `test/__init__.py`

```
from . import test_module_A
```

Inside `test_module_A.py`

```
from unittest import TestCase
from modules.module_A import function_a

class TestModuleA(TestCase):

    def test_function_a(self):
        pass
```

**PROBLEM**:
When I go to the `project-name/data/test` folder and run `nosetests` I receive the following error lines:

```
File "project_name/data/test/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
 ​from . import test_module_A

File "project_name/testing/data/test/test_module_A.py", line 2, in <module>
   ​from modules.module_A import function_a

File "project_name/data/modules/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
   ​from . import module_A

File "project_name/data/modules/module_A.py", line 2, in <module>
   ​from module_B import function_b

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_B'
```

Seems like module_A cannot import module_B when the first when is called from the test. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `modules/module_A.py` contains an *absolute import* (`from module_B import function_b`) in contrast to the *relative imports* in `modules/__init__.py` (`from . import module_B`).

To import a file inside the current package, you'd use *relative imports*.

The correct *relative import* to import `function_b` in `modules/module_A.py` would be

```py
from .module_B import function_b
```